# Extract Only Numbers from a text string in MS access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to extract numbers from a string in the access query builder. Is there any ways to achieve this.

I have tried it in many ways by using MID,REPLACE add other functions with no luck. One of my record look like this.
"Duplicate order Processed by DTC team 3033900434 3034162525 3034703756".

From this string i should be able to take out only the numbers which start with 30.My final output should be like this.3033900434,3034162525,3034703756.

I am using MS ACCESS 2013.

Comment: It looks like you will have to write a user defined function in VBA, which will only be available inside MS Access, unless there are a predetermined number of duplicate orders.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the VBA Code if you have. I am very poor in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always like the above, with only "30..." numbers, you could try --

```
Dupes:iif ( Left(FldName,38) <> "Duplicate order Processed by DTC team ", null,
    Replace(mid(FldName,39),  " ", ",")
```

It picks up all the numbers after the qualifying text, and inserts the commas.

If there are several different qualifying messages there needs to be a way to select appropriate records.  If there are different leading digits on the numbers, some procedural macro would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you said i have several different qualifying messages but in all the messages 30 is common(All numbers start with 30 only)